# Format XML data

Tags: ruby

I'm using this code to format XML data into shell:

```
def modify_trx_id(request_body)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(request_body)
    puts "XML content:"
    doc.to_xml
  end
```

But the output is not very  structured:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<payment_transaction>\n   <transaction_type>sale</transaction_type>\n
```

How I can structure it into properly formatted XML output?

Comment: You have to accept answers that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the output you've received is a properly formatted XML output. Note that `\n` in the string. The only thing that remains is to print it.

The following code:

```
puts modify_trx_id(body)
```

will print something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<payment_transaction>
   <transaction_type>sale</transaction_type>
```

Or, for example, if you need to display it as HTML, there are methods (in `Rails` at least) which convert `\n`'s to `<br/>` and print the content pretty.

Comment: JFYI, it's `<br/>`, not `</br>` :)